# Where to get product-catalog-id

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook marketing API 3.3 version to read product feeds but I don't know where can I get the product-catalog-id.Here is the URL :

```
GET /v3.3/{product-catalog-id}/product_feeds
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your product-catalog-id in the settings page of catalog page (https://www.facebook.com/products/catalogs)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Programatically, I'm using Graph API 13.0, you can fetch your business id via:

`GET me/businesses`
response:
`{ data: [ { id: 12345, ... }, { id: 23456, ... } ] }`

Then use the business ID to fetch product catalogs:

`GET ${businessId}/owned_product_catalogs`
response:
`{ data: [ { id: 12345, name: 'foo', ... }, { id: 23456, name: 'bar', ... } ] }`

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/product-catalog

Comment: When I GET me/businesses I get empty data array, but I have valid businesses

Comment: Sorry @mortezakhadem I haven't worked with the API since early 2022 and haven't got any fresh code I can test with at the moment.  My app has been deactivated and I haven't the heart to try to go through their horrible App Review process again any time soon :)